# calling firestore from python cloud function and app_initialization

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to gcp and I am very confused by the integration between firebase and gcp.

I have a firestore db with some data and a python cloud function that needs to read and write data there.

This is the `main.py` file of one of my cloud functions:

```
import traceback
import firebase
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore




    

#@firestore.transactional        
def _run(data):

    print("Starting transaction. Input data=%s" % data)
    db = firestore.client()
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(data['username']).collection(u'groups').document(data['group'])
    group_ref = db.collection(u'groups').document(data['group'])
    user_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(data['username'])



    doc = doc_ref.get()
    if doc.exists:
        print("user: ", data['username'], ' is already member of the group: ', data['group'])
        return
    else:
        if data['rating'] == "":
            data['rating'] = 50

        x = {'rating': data['rating'],
             'n_games': 0,
             'subscription_time_secs': time.time(),
             'group_ref': group_ref}
        doc_ref.set(x,
                    merge=True)
        group_ref.collection(u'users').document(data['username']).set({'user_ref': user_ref})
        return



def run(request):
    """This endpoint is called as:

    curl  http://0.0.0.0:8080/post -d '{"username": "luca", "group": "padel_roma", "rating": None}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

    """
    data = request.get_json()
    print("Cloud function called with input ", data)

    try:
        firebase_admin.initialize_app()
        _run(data)
        return {'success': True}
    except Exception as e:
        err = traceback.format_exc()
        return {'success': False, 'error': str(err)}
```

It is just an http triggered function that reads and writes some data to my firestore  db. As you can see it calls the  `firebase_admin.initialize_app()`.

I am very confused by this.

If I remove that line I get:
`ValueError(\nValueError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app()`

If I keep that line, instead, the function works the first time I call it but it fails at the second attempt as it is saying that the is already alive.

1. Why do I need to initialize the app if I am only accessing a database?
2. What is the correct way to access firestore from a google cloud function? I have the feeling that this `initialize_app` call is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expected to initialize the Firebase Admin SDK only once per process.  Cloud Functions may handle multiple invocations of a function sequentially in the same process, so you should make sure that initialze_app is only called once globally for that process.  As such, the easiest thing to do is actually just initialize once at the global scope.

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
firebase_admin.initialize_app()
```

Now you can use it in your function without worrying about init again.

Comment: what if I have 2 separate cloud functions? Can they conflict on this `initialize_app`?

Comment: Each function runs isolated from all others in its own set of server instances.  I suggest reading through the documentation to learn more.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec

Comment: Using the code as it raises an exception: `NameError: name 'firebase_admin' is not defined`

Answer should be (imo):

from firebase_admin import firestore
import firebase_admin

firebase_admin.initialize_app()

db = firestore.client()